# Double derivative using chain rule

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I've got a function $f(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)=0$ and want to calculate a double derivative over t.

For the first derivative I received:

${df \over dt}={\partial f \over \partial x}{\partial x \over \partial t}+{\partial f \over \partial y}{\partial y \over \partial t}+{\partial f \over \partial z}{\partial z \over \partial t}+{\partial f \over \partial t}=0$

For the second derivative, I have to calculate:

${d^2f \over dt^2}={\partial \over \partial t}\left ({\partial f \over \partial x}{\partial x \over \partial t}+{\partial f \over \partial y}{\partial y \over \partial t}+{\partial f \over \partial z}{\partial z \over \partial t}+{\partial f \over \partial t} \right )=0$

Did I calculate the first part correctly, because I think I lost sth?

${\partial \over \partial t}\left ({\partial f \over \partial x}{\partial x \over \partial t} \right )=\left ({\partial^2 f \over \partial x \partial x}{\partial x \over \partial t}+{\partial^2 f \over \partial x \partial y}{\partial y \over \partial t}+{\partial^2 f \over \partial x \partial z}{\partial z \over \partial t} \right ){\partial x \over \partial t}+{\partial f \over \partial x}{\partial^2 x \over \partial t^2}$

Comment: Yes. You are doing it correctly, but replace $\partial x/\partial t$ by $dx/dt$ and do the same for the functions $y,z$ as these are functions of the single variable $t$.

Comment: @Medo, thank you!